# Is there any architectural difference between Lightning and Raiden?

Tags: state-channels, raiden

[Lightning](http://lightning.network/) and [Raiden](https://raiden.network/) are payment channel networks for Bitcoin and Ethereum respectively. Is there any difference between these projects in terms of architecture, or is Raiden simply an Ethereum implementation of Lightning?

Comment: The paper [Sprites: Payment Channels that Go Faster than Lightning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05812) in Appendices D-E provides an overview and comparison of various payment channel proposals, namely Lightning, Duplex, Raiden, and Sprites.

Comment: Channels in Lightning are designed to have a lifetime, while a Raiden channel can run forever

Comment: @neuromouse Cn you provide the source? From what I understand from the [Lightning paper](http://lightning.network/lightning-network-paper.pdf), Lightning also have an infinite lifetime (due to breach remedy transactions).

Comment: Everybody seems to be so excited about second layer solutions, but no one seems to understand how they work exactly. Just... wow :( 50 rep is awarded to 0x0.

Comment: I've stuided a bit about how Raiden works, but haven't spent much time on Lightning. The source is from a Raiden developer on a podcast, so it might not be reliable: https://player.fm/series/oktahedron/oh007-raiden

Answer (score 1):

The [Raiden FAQ](https://raiden.network/faq.html#lightning) states that it supports ERC20 tokens instead of just Ether. Going a step further, [Raiden 2.0](https://raiden.network/faq.html#raidos) wishes to generalize state channels in order to make faster dapps.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've spend quite some time wrapping my head around the mechanics of Lightning (commitment tx's, breach remedy tx's, timelocks, etc). I'm wondering, to what extend does Raiden port those to Ethereum, considering the completely different account structure (UTXOs vs account balances)?

Comment: I cannot. Now I see what you mean by "architectural." This might be detail that you can only get by reading source code.